# How can I increase a number that is inside a string by one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery plugin that creates tabs to navigate through, all tabs are loaded dynamically except the last one which is hardcoded. I still want to navigate like usual so that tab needs to have the id of the tab before it +1.

These are the two elements that make the tabs work:

```
<a href="#step-10" class="nav-link">Vul je keuze aan</a>
<div id="step-10" class="" style="">
```

Say for example like above there are 10 steps/tabs, then the hardcoded step needs to have:

```
<a href="#step-11" class="nav-link">Vul je keuze aan</a>
<div id="step-11" class="" style="">
```

How can I do that? I can't just parse it as a number and increase by one since the number is inside a string alongside with `step-`. How can I remove the number from that string, increase it and put the new number back?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to parse the string and retrieve the integer value. However using incremental `id` attributes is often an anti-pattern, because it creates more work than necessary (as in this case) and make maintenance harder. I'd strongly suggest you get rid of the `id` and use DOM traversal methods to find related elements when the `a` is clicked - in this case `next('div')`

Comment: An alternative for your harcoded/fixed tab is to not give it a number at all:  `<a href='#step-last'`.. `<div id="step-last"` - then no need to change the number.  (or something more meaningful, `step-final-choice`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this question. `How can I remove the number from that string, increase it and put the new number back?`
Let's say I have the id assigned to a var

```
var id = "step-11"
var splittedId = id.split("-");    //["step", "11"]
var no = parseInt(splittedId[1]);  // 11
var step = splittedId[0];          // "step"
var newId = step+"-"+(++splittedId[1]); // "step-12"
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it with above code. I still had to add the `-` again though since it was splitted.

Answer (score 0):

A thing you can do is take all the divs with id like `step-` count them and put this count +1 like the code below

```
 const test = document.querySelectorAll("div[id*='step-']");
 document.getElementsByClassName('testclass')[0].id='step-'+(test.length+1)
```